# Compact set in sequence of resolvet set of convergent sequence of linear and bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I'm working in the following excercise:

Let $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq\mathcal{L}(E)$ and $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $T_n\to T$. Show that for every compac set $K\subseteq R(T)$ (resolvent set of T) exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
K \subseteq R(T_n) \quad \forall n \geq n_0.
$$

My attempt:

Let $K$ a subset of $R(T)$, then
$$
K = \bigcup_{i=1}^m B(\lambda_i,\varepsilon)
$$
On the other hand, since $T_n \to T$, then
$$
(T_n - \lambda Id)^{-1} \to (T - \lambda Id)^{-1}
$$
even more, the last statement is true for every $\lambda$ in $K$.

Take $n_0 = \max\{m,s\}$ where $s\in\mathbb{N}$ came from convergence of $T_n\to T$.

Let $\lambda \in K$.  We want to prove that $\lambda \in R(T_n)$ where $n\geq n_0$, i.e., we want to prove that $T_n-\lambda Id$ is invertible. Note that
$$
T_n-\lambda Id = (T-\lambda_j Id)(Id - (T-\lambda_j Id)^{-1}((T-\lambda_j Id)-(T-\lambda Id)))
$$
The previous equality comes from
$$
T = A(Id-A^{-1}(A-T))
$$
where $\lambda_j$ satisfies that $|\lambda - \lambda_j|<\varepsilon$ (since $K$ is compact). Then, if
$$\|(T-\lambda_j Id)^{-1}((T-\lambda_j Id)-(T-\lambda Id))\|<1$$
following the desire result. In fact,
\begin{align}\|(T-\lambda_j Id)^{-1}((T-\lambda_j Id)-(T-\lambda Id))\| &\leq \|(T-\lambda_j Id)^{-1}\| \|(T-\lambda_j Id)-(T-\lambda Id)\| \\\\ & \leq M \|(T-\lambda_j Id)-(T-\lambda Id)\| \\\\ &\leq M (\|T_n-T\| + |\lambda-\lambda_j|) \\\\ & < 1 \end{align}

Is correct my proof? Thanks

Comment: There is a misprint in the first (long) formula, as the index $n$ is missing on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the simplest proof is by contradiction, based on the fact that the set of noninvertible operators is closed.

Assume by contradiction that there exist: an increasing sequence $n_k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda_k\in K,$ such that $T_{n_k}-\lambda_kI$ are not invertible. As $K$ is compact we may assume (by restricting to a subsequence) that $\lambda_k$ is convergent to $\lambda\in K.$ As $T_{n_k}-\lambda_kI\to T-\lambda I$ the operator $T-\lambda I$ is noninvertible, a contradiction.